# User Access Roles In Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have Firestore setup as shown in the images below.
[image: first image][image: second image][image: third image]

I am trying ensure that a user can only have access to projects of a specific company provided the user is authenticated (email and password), email-verified and is part of the users collection (by verifying with UID) for that company based on a specific role (eg. manager, dancer, choreographer).

I have created some rules as shown below but it is not working as expected. Thank you in advance for the contribution.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    //create user creates own data in users collection
    match /companies/company_id/users{
        allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email_verified == true;
    }
    
    //user should be allowed to create or delete own data. 
    //Only managers should be allowed to delete data of others
    match /companies/company_id/users/{user_id}{
        allow read, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == user_id;
    }
    
    match /companies/{company_id}/projects {
      allow write: if isManager(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/{company_id}/users/$(request.auth.uid))) || isChoreographer(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/{company_id}/users/$(request.auth.uid)));
      allow read: if isDancer(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/{company_id}/users/$(request.auth.uid)));
    }
    
    match /companies/{company_id}/project/{project_id} {
      allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/{company_id}/users/$(request.auth.uid)) == request.auth.uid;
    }
    
    function isManager(database){
        return database.data.role == "manager";
    }
    
    function isChoreographer(database){
        return database.data.role == "choreographer";
    }
    
    function isDancer(database){
        return database.data.role == "dancer";
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I have included a curl script I used trying to access one of the firestore rules.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project_somthin/databases/(default)/documents/companies/company_a/users/MSTJMcwggcGwrXgEgwl5' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer token_id'
```

I go the error:

> {
> "error": {
> "code": 403,
> "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
> "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
> } }

Comment: Can you please specify what part of your security rules aren't working? You can try checking your rules by using the [Firebase Security Playground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator).

Comment: None of them are working. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal or reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how you access your security rules? Also do keep in mind that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters) — queries are all or nothing.

Comment: @RJC , minimal code included in the edit.

Comment: You can check this [post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-group-based-permissions-for-cloud-firestore-72859cdec8f6) that focus on group-based permissions, and as I've stated before, you can try to run/check your security rules one by one in [Firebase Security Playground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator) just to verify if there's a working rule on your end.